# New date for every section using fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm using the report format and would like to a new date to appear on the right header of each section (I can input these dates manually). My knowledge is very basic, so far I have managed to set this in the preamble but I only know how to produce one date across the entire document (given below), rather than updating in each section.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\today}
```

As an overview, my document will be structured like this to record notes from eight meetings, four in each of two chapters.

-Chapter 1
-Section 1.1 (date 1)
-Section 1.2 (date 2)
-Section 1.3 (date 3)
-Section 1.4 (date 4)

-Chapter 2
-Section 2.1 (date 5)
-Section 2.2 (date 6)
-Section 2.3 (date 7)
-Section 2.4 (date 8)

If someone could provide me with some code that I can use at the beginning of each section where I could input the date, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Hi, do you need ongoing dates (e.g. where the day or month is increased by one every section)? Or you really want to set each date manually? And which `documentclass` are you using, since most classes define `section` etc. differently.

Comment: Hi @lukeflo, setting each date manually is needed as the meetings are not consistently spaced apart. My document class is report, thanks!

Comment: You can use `\date{...}` to reset `\today` to be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just defined a new command `\datesection` which takes up to 3 arguments:

`\datesection[<short title>]{<section title>}[<date/right header content>]`

- The first 2 (optional and mandatory) are the standard `\section` arguments
- The last/trailing optional argument sets the right header

It also has a starred version, which works like the `\section*` command:

```latex
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\NewDocumentCommand{\datesection}{s O{#3} m O{\empty}}{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
    \section*{#3}
    \fancyhead[R]{#4}
    }{
    \section[#2]{#3}
    \fancyhead[R]{#4}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\datesection{title}[\today]
\blindtext

\clearpage

\datesection[short title]{longer title}[tomorrow]
\blindtext

\clearpage

\datesection*{title 2}[yesterday]
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Hope that works for you!

Comment: Thank you @lukeflo, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I've just noticed that this changes the section names in the table of contents to "-NoValue-" instead of the section title, would there be an easy way to fix this?

Comment: Oh, didn't check the TOC. I guess it occurs if you leave the first optional argument empty. Right now I've no access to my PC. Will check it ASAP.

Comment: Ah silly me - you're spot on, thanks!

Comment: @LaurenS, no, you were right. Didn't thought about that `xparse` inserts `-NoValue-` for empty optional arguments. Fixed the `NewDocumentCommand`. Now it works with empty optional arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a variable by using `\def\<variablename>` And then just update the variable with each new section.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\kdate{4}

\section{Section 1.1  - \kdate}

\def\kdate{5}

\section{Section 1.2  - \kdate}

\def\kdate{6}

\section{Section 1.3  - \kdate}


\end{document}
```

I've used `kdate` for a variable name. You can use whatever you want, just make sure it doesn't clash with a pre-existing variable or command.

[image]

**Edit:**

If you are using the `fancyhdr` package to build your headers, you can add that variable to your `\fancyhead` command:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
 \fancyhead[RE,LO]{\kdate}
```

Comment: But the date is not in the header as asked for by the OP.

Comment: @lukeflo That's because OP did not provide an MWE showing how they are defining the header. If they are using `fancyhdr` they can just add their variable to `\pagestyle{fancy}` in the preamble. But I don't know how they are building their headers. I've updated my response with this example.

Comment: Thank you @KennethOdle, your edit is really helpful - much appreciated!